# How to resolve an issue with overloading operators in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I can get the file to compile fine. However, when I try to test if the operator is overloaded correctly I get the error message:

```
*Main> MyFloat (2,3) + MyFloat(3,3)

<interactive>:19:15:
Ambiguous occurrence `+'
It could refer to either `Main.+', defined at problem1.hs:3:16
                      or `Prelude.+',
                         imported from `Prelude' at problem1.hs:1:1
                         (and originally defined in `GHC.Num')
```

The code I am using is:

```
data MyFloat = MyFloat (Int, Int)

MyFloat (a, b) + MyFloat (c, d) = ((fromIntegral a)/ (fromIntegral(order a)) * 10^b) 
Prelude.+ ((fromIntegral c)/ (fromIntegral(order c)) * 10^d)



order :: Int -> Int 
order b | b == 0 = 0 
        | otherwise = ((ceiling ((logBase 10 (abs (fromIntegral b))))) Prelude.+ 1)
```

Am I misunderstanding how overload operators correctly, or is there a different problem entirely?

Comment: The error is that you have defined your own (+) operator, which conflicts with the standard one from the prelude....

Comment: @jamshidh So how can I tell the complier when adding these data types it should use the Main.+ or do I have to go MyFloat (a,b) Main.+ MyFloat (b,c) each time?

Comment: You can import Prelude hiding (+), but this is considered bad form.  See below for another way.

Comment: There's no operator overloading in Haskell. You can only add new instances to typeclasses, with similar consequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really want to do is make your class an instance of Num

```
instance Num MyFloat where
    x + y = <put in your definition here>
```

Note that Num will require a definition of (*), abs, signum, fromInteger, (negate | (-)) also

In haskell, one typically overloads functions using class definitions.

Comment: As @chi points out, "typical" isn't strong enough; you can _only_ "overload" functions with typeclasses. Even then overloading isn't really a particularly helpful way of thinking about what's going on.